# Python load json helper method not working

Tags: python, json

I've defined a helper method to load json from a string or file like so:

```
def get_json_from_string_or_file(obj):
    if type(obj) is str:
        return json.loads(obj)
    return json.load(obj)
```

When I try it with a file it fails on the `load` call with the following exception:

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 291, in load
   **kw)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
   return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
   obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
   raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I have triple checked my json file and it is definitely not empty, it just has a simple foo bar key value mapping.

Also, I'm feeding the json file into the method like so:

`os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "test.json")`

Any idea whats going on here?

EDIT: I changed my helper method to the following to fix up the mistakes addressed in the answers and comments and it's still not working, i'm getting the same error when I pass in an already open file.

```
def get_json_from_file(_file):
    if type(_file) is str:
        with open(_file) as json_file:
            return json.load(json_file)
    return json.load(_file)
```

EDIT #2: I FOUND THE PROBLEM! this error occurs if you call `json.load` on an open file twice in a row. It turns out that another part of my application had already got that file open.

Here is some reproduction code:

```
with open("/test.json") as f:
    json.load(f)
    json.load(f)
```

Comment: You are passing it a string of the filepath? Then trying to load that, non-json, string with `.loads()`?

Comment: @wwii Yes you're right please see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code works.

```
import os
import json

def get_json_from_string_or_file(obj):
    if type(obj) is str:
        return json.loads(obj)
    return json.load(obj)

filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "test.json")
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    result = get_json_from_string_or_file(f)
    print(result)
```

`ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` is reproduced when I passed the filename to the function, like `get_json_from_string_or_file(filename)`.

---

#### 2nd version

```
import os
import json

def get_json_from_file(_file):
    if type(_file) is str: # <-- unnecessary if
        with open(_file) as json_file:
            return json.load(json_file)
    return json.load(_file)

filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "test.json")
result = get_json_from_file(filename)

print(result)
# python2: {u'foo': u'bar'}
# python3: {'foo': 'bar'}
```

Comment: Please see my second edit - I found the real problem. I guess it's a different problem than to what my original question was...

Comment: @Ogen OK! Congratulations!

Comment: So the issue is probably the 'r' ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'd comment but I lack the rep. Can you paste a sample JSON file that doesn't work into a pastebin? I'll edit this into an answer after that if I can.

Comment: It's just this:
{
  "foo" : "bar"
}

Comment: What's the output when you print obj?

Comment: The output was just the name of the file.